# In Percy Jackson's universe, are any Cyclopes NOT children of Poseidon?

Tags: percy-jackson

When Tyson gets into Camp Half-Blood, he isn't "claimed" by anyone and is supposed to be bunked in Hermes Cabin, until Poseidon shows a trident sign above his head.

Yet, the rest of the books seems to imply that any Cyclopes around are all Poseidon's kids.

Is there any canon information that not 100% of them are and that there was a reason to doubt Tyson's parentage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, found a canon confirmation that the answer is "yes".

> Annabeth nodded. “I remember now. When the Titans ruled, they imprisoned **Gaea and Ouranos’s earlier children— the Cyclopes** and the Hekatonkheires.”

This is from book #4, *The Battle of the Labyrinth*, when they first glimpse Kampe and one of Hekatonkheires in chapter 7, *TYSON LEADS A JAILBREAK*.

Answer (score 3):

**Most** of the cyclopes are children of Poseidon but not all. There are the three eldest cyclopes – Arges, Brontes, and Steropes – the sons of Gaea and Ouranos. Some cyclopes are also the children of other cyclopes, which seems to happen mostly among the Hyperborean (Northern) Cyclopes. It is also implied that most of the Southern Cyclopes are the get of Poseidon.

It's been some time since I last read some a Percy Jackson novel but a quick Google search did turn up [this wiki](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Cyclops) entry. Maybe someone else who has read the novels recently is able to dig up some references.

Comment: If the Wiki isn't referenced, it could be just as likely someone made it up.

Comment: @DVK I can confirm that The Lost Hero novel states what the wiki does.